# Не происходит инъекция в конструктор WebApiController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, owin, ninject

Дали задание заинджектать в конструктор контроллера класс Repository реализующий интерфейс Repository. Нашёл пример пример вот такой конфигурации

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(API.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(API.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace API.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    using DataAccess;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);//Добавил строчку вот тут

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<Repository>().ToConstructor(i => new Repository(i.Inject<QueueDB>()));
            kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот он сам контроллер. В конструкторе передаю интерфейс IRepository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using DataAccess;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        IRepository _repository;
        public ValuesController(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

При этом реализация интерфейса, класс Repository принимает в качестве аргумента конструктора интерфейс IContext (Который мы тоже заинджектали) у который реализует класс QueueDB.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Entity;

namespace DataAccess
{
    public class Repository : IRepository
    {
        private IContext _context;
        public Repository(IContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("Context is null");

            this._context = context;
        }
        public void AddQueue(Queue queue)
        {
            _context.Queues.Add(queue);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void AddUser(User user)
        {
            _context.Users.Add(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void AddUserInQueue(User user, Queue queue)
        {
            UserState state = new UserState
            {
                Queue = queue,
                User = user
            };
            _context.States.Add(state);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void DeleteQueue(Queue queue)
        {
            _context.Delete(queue);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void DeleteUser(User user)
        {
            _context.Delete(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void DeleteUserFromQueue(User user, Queue queue)
        {
            UserState state = user.States.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Queue.Id.Equals(queue.Id));//Яне буду использовать include, буду надется на lazy loading

            if (state == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("User (systemName: {0}) not a member Queue (id: {1})", user.SystemName, queue.Id));
            else
            {
                _context.Delete(state);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }

        public void EditQueue(Queue edit)
        {
            _context.Update(edit);
        }

        public void EditUser(User edit)
        {
            _context.Update(edit);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public ICollection<Queue> GetAllQueue()
        {
            return _context.Queues.ToList();
        }

        public ICollection<User> GetAllUser()
        {
            return _context.Users.ToList();
        }

        public Queue GetQueueById(Guid id)
        {
            Queue queue = _context.Queues.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id.Equals(id));

            if (queue == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("Queue (id: {0}) not fount", id));
            else
                return queue;
        }

        public User GetUserBySystemName(string systemName)
        {
            User user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.SystemName.Equals(systemName));

            if (user == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("User (systemName: {0}) not fount", systemName));
            else
                return user;
        }

        public bool HasUser(string systemName)
        {
            return _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.SystemName.Equals(systemName)) != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Но при обращении к контроллеру ValuesController появляется ошибка:

```
<Error>
<Message>Произошла ошибка.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Произошла ошибка при попытке создать контроллер типа "ValuesController". Убедитесь в том, что контроллер имеет общедоступный конструктор без параметров.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) в System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>Произошла ошибка.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Тип "API.Controllers.ValuesController" не содержит конструктор по умолчанию
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
в System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) в System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType) в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

Пример я брал вот от [сюда](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/dependency-injection-by-using-ninject-in-web-api/)

Comment: Попробуйте `kernel.Bind<IContext>().To<QueueDB>();` вместо `kernel.Bind<Repository>().ToConstructor(...)`

Comment: @kvm результат остаётся тем же.